# height 100% na div não funciona

Tags: html, css

Já tentei de tudo mas meu height:100% não funciona o que devo fazer?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100 %;
}
.margin - site {
  width: 615px;
  margin: 47px auto;
  background - color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  word - wrap: break -word;
  border - radius: 3px;
  display: table;
}
.margin - right {
  width: 255px;
  height: 100 %;
  float: right;
  height: -webkit - calc(100 % -100px);
  height: -moz - calc(100 % -100px);
  height: calc(100 % -100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="margin-site">
  <div class="margin-right">
    conteudo right
  </div>
  conteudo site
</div>
```

Comment: Cara cade o html para que possamos examinar melhor?
Certo você declarou `html` e a `body` com altura 100%, mas e essa classe `.margin-right` ela é filho de algum pai ? Se sim esse pai também tem que estar declarado com altura 100%.

Comment: @ThomsonTorvalds é filho sim, atualizei o post com o html

Comment: @ThomsonTorvalds eu tentei colocar height:100%; no pai também no caso .margin-site e não deu certo. :/

Answer (score 2):

Para um elemento filho, no seu caso `margin-right`, utilizar `height:100%` o elemento pai, no seu caso `margin-site`, também deve possui `height:100%;`

Devido a `height: calc(100% - 100px);` o elemento `margin-right` está com height de `100%-100px` e o elemento pai, `margin-site` também possui `padding:10px`, por isso o elemento filho não ocupa toda a `height` do elemento pai

```css
    html, body {
    margin:0px;
    height:100%;
    }
.margin-site {
    width: 615px;
    height:100%;
    margin: 47px auto;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: table;
}
    .margin-right {
        width: 255px;
        height: 100%;
        float: right;
        height: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
        height: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);
        height: calc(100% - 100px);
        background:green;
    }
```

```html
<div class="margin-site">
<div class="margin-right">
conteudo right
</div>
conteudo site
</div>
```

> Coloquei o background vermelho e verde para ser visível que o elemento `margin-right` está com height apropriado.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, mas ainda não está funcionando e fiz tudo como você fez. Tanto que aqui no exemplo também não funcionou :/

Comment: Funcionou sim, acontece que no exemplo a `height:100%` da body corresponde a `203px`. Seu elemento `margin-right` possui uma height de `100%-100px`, e seu elemento pai `margin-site` possui uma `padding:10px` totalizando `20px` de height, fazendo os cálculos `203-100-20` totaliza exatos `83px` o que corresponde exatamente a `height` do elemento `margin-right`

Comment: Se você retirar `margin:47px auto;` e `padding:10px;` do elemento `margin-site`, e retirar `height: calc(100% - 100px);` do elemento `margin-right`, verá que os dois elementos preenchem a tela, exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/leonardorodrigues/f8dL92up/

Comment: Eu não posso retirar o margin: auto; pois eu preciso da box centralizada, e mesmo retirando o problema continua, o problema pode ser em meu css? Eu tenho outra box do site que o height 100% funciona perfeitamente

Comment: Não precisa retirar `margin`, eu falei que se você retirasse iria ficar mais fácil perceber que `height:100%` estava funcionando. Você está se confundindo um pouco e isso dificulta te ajudar, `height:100%` está funcionando perfeitamente nos 2 exemplos que lhe passei, acontece que `height: calc(100% - 100px);` defini que o elemento irá subtrair `100px` do tamanho máximo disponível para `height`. 
**VEJA:** https://jsfiddle.net/leonardorodrigues/f8dL92up/1/. O `margin-right` está tomando o tamanho máximo disponível para `height`

Comment: Eu entendi. Eu coloquei como estava no meu site no fiddle e funcionou, mas no site não funciona. Deve ser outra coisa que está impedindo que isso funcione.